# Implicit Function Theorem -Confusion-

Tags: calculus, multivariable-calculus

I am trying to figure out what the implicit function theorem is. Can anyone explain it to me? I was reading the wiki: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Implicit_function_theorem but still don't understand it too well.

Why does the function $f: R^{n+m} \rightarrow R^m$ have to be continuously differentiable?

Comment: [It doesn't need to be](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Implicit_function_theorem#Implicit_functions_from_non-differentiable_functions).

Comment: You can find many documents about IFT, for instance you can look the notes http://rutherglen.science.mq.edu.au/wchen/lnmvafolder/mva03.pdf

Comment: It doesn't (as @Git Gud said). It depends on what properties you want for the implicit function. Read the Generalizations section in  http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Implicit_function_theorem

Comment: @user40615 THanks, that article is good.

Comment: You're welcome. Good luck.

Answer (score 0):

It might be easiest to look at an example from $R^1$ to $R^1$ that's differentiable but not continuously differentiable. My favorite is 
$$
f(x) = \begin{cases} 
x^2 \sin (\frac{1}{x}) & x \ne 0 \\
0 & x = 0
\end{cases}.
$$

This function has a discontinuous derivative, but the derivative is zero at many many points arbitrarily near the origin, so the preimage of the origin ends up not being an embedded submanifold (of dimension 0) in $R^1$.

I hope this example helps you resolve at least some confusion.

Comment: But $f'(0)=0$ violates the maximal rank condition.

Comment: Right. Good point, Ted. Add $x$ to the function, i.e., $x + x^2 \sin(\frac{1}{x})$ has rank 1 at the origin, is differentiable, but not continuously differentiable.

Comment: But now $f^{-1}(0)$ is just $0$, certainly locally.