# Implicit function theorem solving of a set of equations

Tags: calculus, real-analysis, implicit-function-theorem

So i was reading the following note on the implicit function theorem:

https://rutherglen.science.mq.edu.au/wchen/lnmvafolder/mva03.pdf

I understand everything for the most part with regards to the theoretical part, but on page 6 of the pdf halfway down on the right after we have established that the partial derivative is $-8z_0w_0$ the author says that we can solve for $z$ and $w$ and proceeds to show that

$$z = g_1(x,y) = \sqrt{1-x^2}$$  and $$w = g_2(x,y) = \sqrt{1-y^2}$$

Now i understand by the fact that the partial doesn't equal $0$ at certain points we can solve for the variables from $F(x,y,z,w) = 0$, but what happened to the rest of the variables? I mean based on the original equations i don't see how the $x$, $y$, $z$, $w$ vanish when isolating one of them.

I know it is asking alot to look at the document and such but the context is better stated through that way. Thanks

Comment: So apparently i can't add the link:  Http://noterutherglen.science.mq.edu.au/wchen/lnmvafolder/mva03.pdf

Comment: It seems like there is something wrong with the link.

Comment: It came from this post http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/624432/implicit-function-theorem-confusion?rq=1    but for some reason it won't work

Comment: How did you get the link to work @slo?

Comment: I am not quite sure what you had wrong causing it to not show up. I just inserted the correct link... Maybe you have to have enough reputation.